# Changing event types in Open Atruim Calendar

Tags: drupal, open-atrium

I am trying to change the event types in the Open Atrium Calendar. I have gone through all the settings in the UI and I cannot find an option anywhere. Does anyone know how to change these through the code?

Answer (score 0):

Admin --> Content --> Taxonomy